# Beginner can't import a files to an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, file, import, scanf

I'm having a headache after trying to figure out what's the problem behind my code
Basically I'm trying to read a file and fill an array with these elements.

Here is the code of the structure I'm using

```
typedef struct  {
    void* * data  ;         
    size_t max_size;      
    size_t actual_size;    

    void* (*delete_data)(void*); 
    int (*equal_data)(void*,void*); 
    void (*fprint_data)(void*, FILE*); 
} * table_t;
```

and here's my code

```
   void get_dico(table_t tab , const char * dico ) {
     FILE *fp = NULL ;
     int i = 0 ;
      if((fp = fopen(dico,"r")) != NULL){
        char word[256];
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s",word) == true ){          
          tab->data[i] = word ;
          i ++ ;
        }
      fclose(fp);
      }

     }
```

and here's the dico file

```
a
b
c
s
```

NOW the problem occurs at the end of the get dico where I find that my  array which is tab contains only the last char wish is "s" it's seems that tab = {s,s,s,s} instead of {a,b,c,d}.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you meant `word` to be `mot` then `tab->data[i] = word` is assigning a pointer to data which will die after the end of the function.

Comment: In addition to comment above, you assign the very same pointer to each element in your array. That's why all contain the same content. And all of them are illegal to access after leaving the function.

Comment: I edited so they match mot and word ( tried to translate to english and forgot a word)

Comment: You could try `tab->data[i] = strdup(word);` which will allocate memory and copy the string.

Comment: Aside this `fscanf(fp,"%s",word) == true` is incorrect. it only "works" here because `true` has the value `1`, but `fscanf` does not return a `bool` type. it returns the number of successful conversions. So here you should check `fscanf(fp,"%s",word) == 1`

Comment: oh god thanks its working !!!!! Didn't know about this function before thank you

Comment: Use with caution: `strdup()` is a non-standard function.

Comment: I will thank you , juste starting in C. Have a nice day !